# Powershell: Get-WmiObject cannot run asJob in loop

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

I want to sometimes check some info from our servers in domains. In this example, I am trying to remotely get windows versions (just one server, currently without loop):

```
$cr=Get-Credential "domain\adm_user"
$computer="serverA"
Invoke-Command { Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Namespace root/cimv2 -Computer $computer -Credential $cr | Format-List -Property Name, OSArchitecture, SerialNumber} -AsJob -ComputerName .
Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Output:

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
```

Seems, that scriptblock {} cannot see variable `$computer`.
When I replace variable `-computer $computer` to name of server, it is working.

Comment: The correct parameter is `-ComputerName `- you are using -Computer?

Comment: Computer and ComputerName is alias. I tried long name and output (error) is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variable expansion inside Invoke-Command use a param block and specify arguments:

```
$computer = 'localhost'
Invoke-Command {param($computer) Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computername $computer } -ArgumentList $computer
```

Working on PS v5.